# FLUTTER FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. with attached build.gradle code

Tags: flutter

I am getting an build error as

```
Launching lib\main. Dart on LE2111 in debug mode...
Building with Flutter multidex support enabled.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\AJITH\OneDrive\Desktop\projects\rekhitha startup\Farmer_Vendor_rsi\android\build.gradle' line: 27

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
> Build completed with 1 failures.
   > com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/android/build/api/extension/AndroidComponentsExtension

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                           2,154ms
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

and my code is hear

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.4.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I tried changing packages, cleaned the package, and reinstalled it, but I'm still encountering the same error. After running 'flutter clean,' I executed 'flutter pub get,' and even after using these commands, the issue persists when I run 'flutter run.'

And i can able to run the app in chrome and Microsoft edge but unable to run it in physically connected device